# Easy Admin does not show the relationships

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

- I am training Symfony 5.2 using [the fast track](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/9-backend.html)
- I am at [step 9](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/9-backend.html) configuring EASY Admin
- Easy Admin creates CRUD Controllers one for Conference and one for Comment (a Comment belongs to a Conference)
- the problem is when I create a new Comment EasyAdmin does not propose me a select list to choose the Conference it belongs to and the creation finishes with a SQL Exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also stuck in this step for the same reason !! But I found the solution in this [link](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/3477/653593474)

In sum, at *Admin/CommentCrudController.php*, you should add this:

```
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FormField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextEditorField;
```

and override function configureFields like this:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        FormField::addPanel('Conference'),
        AssociationField::new('conference')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setHelp('help text'),
        FormField::addPanel('Comment'),
        TextField::new('author')
            ->setHelp('Your name'),
        TextEditorField::new('text', 'Comment')
            ->setHelp('help text'),
        EmailField::new('email', 'Email Address')
            ->setHelp('Your valid email address'),
        DateTimeField::new('createdAt'),
        TextField::new('photoFilename')
    ];

}
```

Now, it should work fine as for me :-)

Comment: This answers an issue you will only experience when reading  https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/9-backend.html.  Thanks though